# C fork in a while loop [continuously check for something and fork a child and kill the other one]

Tags: c, linux, fork

say my code is something like this (C, Linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void zombie1(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        // do_some_stuff;
    }
}

void zombie2(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        // do_some_stuff;
    }
}

int which_zombie(void)
{
    check_for_this_or_that();

    if(this_happened)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(that_happened)
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

int main(void){

    // fork()
    // here i want to call which_zombie() every 10 seconds and run one of the zombies
    // and kill the other one...    
}
```

how to do that while main process remains intact ? inside the main function, i'm calling a fork() and in the child process i'm calling which_zombie and if one of them already exist kill it and running the other one. i have tried this but no success! :

```
int main(void)
{
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        int type;
        int zombie1_pid = 0;
        int zombie2_pid = 0;
        while(1)
        {
            type = which_zombie();
            if(type == 1)
            {
                if(zombie2_pid != 0)
                {
                    kill(zombie2_pid, SIGTERM);
                    zombie2_pid = 0;
                }

                zombie1_pid = fork();
                if(zombie1_pid == 0)
                {
                    zombie1();
                }

            }
            else if(type == 2)
            {
                if(zombie1_pid != 0)
                {
                    kill(zombie1_pid, SIGTERM);
                    zombie1_pid = 0;
                }

                zombie2_pid = fork();
                if(zombie2_pid == 0)
                {
                    zombie2();
                }

            }


            sleep(10);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // parent ...
    }
}
```

from man pages(waitpid) i found that should add a call to waitpid somewhere [childs remain in zombie state]. so what's wrong in this code ?

---

**edit1:**
just to be clear, the program should check the "type" every 10 seconds in the while loop and fork func1 or func2 based on the type and every time if the type changed it kills the child process and "fork"s the other one. of course when we closed the parent all child processes should exit too...
thanks in adv.

---

**edit2:**
Chris' answer solved the problem but to kill all children and keep the parent alive i found that i should add a signal handler like so:

```
pid_t parent_pid;

void sigquit_handler(int sig)
{
    assert(sig == SIGQUIT);
    pid_t self_pid = getpid();
    if(parent_pid != self_pid)
    {
        _exit(0);
    }
}
```

**main:**

```
    parent_pid = getpid();
    signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit_handler);
    kill(-parent_pid, SIGQUIT);
    int status;
    int i;


        for(;;)
        {
            pid_t child = wait(&status);
            if(child > 0 && WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
            {
                printf("child %d exited successfully.\n", (int)child);
            }
            else if(child < 0 && errno == EINTR)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else{
                perror("wait");
                abort();
            }
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Please also devise a new terminology than 'zombie'; a process that is running an infinite loop is not a zombie. It may not be useful, but it isn't one of the living dead. A zombie process is one which has died but whose parent has not yet waited for it. Also, as you're working on Linux, abjure thine heathen ways and never again pronounce the incantation `void main()`; the `main()` function on Linux _always_ returns an `int`! Also, if GCC didn't complain about that, you aren't using enough warning flags on your compilation.

Comment: sorry dude. got your point but i didn't mean that! just name it func1 and func2 which are called in the main process as child! also i'm not professional in C :) seems `kill(zombie1_pid, SIGTERM)` or `kill(zombie2_pid, SIGTERM)` won't properly kill the child so they will execute together !

Comment: just edited the question to be clear "what im asking" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have created a kind of fork-bomb.  It's true that if you don't use waitpid() once in a while, a bunch of defunct processes will start to pile up.

```
int main(void)
{
    int zpid = -1, type, oldtype=0;

    while(1) {
        type = which_zombie();
        if (type != oldtype) {
            if (zpid != -1)
                    kill(zpid, SIGTERM);
            zpid = fork();
            if (zpid == 0) {
                if (type == 1)
                    zombie1();
                else
                    zombie2();
            }
            oldtype = type;
        }
        waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG);
        sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: yep it works fine. i think waitpid in your code did the trick. thank you :)

Comment: this code works fine but when i kill the parent, the child doesn't exit ! i have tried to getpgid and kill it to kill all of them. (`kill(getpgid(), SIGTERM)`) but actually im forking the while loop itself [`fork(); if(){while(){....}}`] and i want the parent to remain intact !